# how to pass pandas series element to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I want to check if an error occurred.
I have this two dataframes, from excel files:

Log_frame is a dataframe of log files, reporting data recording and error:

```
               Time       Voltage[V]  Freq[Hz] Speed    Motor_Stt: ErrNo
           0  10:00          220         50     30           1      0
           1  10:10          220         50     30           1      0
           2  10:20          220         50      0           2      3601
           3  10:30          220         47      0           1      1500
           4  10:40          250         50      0           1      7707
           5  10:50          220         50      0           2      3601
           6  11:00          220         50      0           2      3601
           7  11:10          220         47      0           1      1500
           8  11:20          220         50     30           1      0
           9  11:30          220         50     30           1      0
```

Dev_frame is the dataframe of error description:

```
    Fehler-Nr.         Descr                Cause

0   1500          Chk_Voltage      Voltage out of range
1   7707           Chk_Freq.       Freq. out of range
2   3601         Chk_Motor_Stt          Motor_defec
3   7704          switch_trip           chk_over_curr
```

from Log_frame I can check if, which and how many errors occurred during a day by:

```
Err_log = Log_frame['ErrNo']
p = Err_log[Err_log != 0].drop_duplicates('first').reset_index(drop=True)
```

and this result is a pandas series:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    3601
1    1500
2    7707
```

I can "pass" first error (or second and all the other) by this:

```
Dev_Err = Dev_frame['Fehler-Nr.']
n = Dev_Err[Dev_Err == p.iloc[0]] #or 1, 2 and so on
```

I was wondering how to loop trough p.iloc[i].
Should I use a for loop or can be done by any pandas function

EDIT: e.g. if I put 1 in p.iloc[] I can get:

```
0   1500
```

if 2:

```
1   7707
```

Comment: Dev_frame doesn't have the column `Fehler-Nr.`, can you add it to the question?

Comment: yes, please add ''Fehler-Nr.' in question and i guess you want to subset your Dev_Err df by p, please explain question a bit more.

Comment: As other highlighted add "Fehler-Nr" as column. you can use "merge" function of pandas to get the desired result.

Comment: Edited. I tried with a loop cycle, incrementing iloc[i] but it seems not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create a loop to check each value, you can use `isin` method that `pandas.DataFrame` has as following:

```
n = dev_frame[dev_frame['Fehler-Nr.'].isin(p)]['Fehler-Nr.']
```

which is going to return:

```
0    1500
1    7707
2    3601
Name: Fehler-Nr., dtype: int64
```

Ref: [pandas.DataFrame.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas and going for for loops you are wrong. Use pandas vectorised operations. These are done using (simple exaple)

```
df.apply(some function, axis)
```

I'm not 100% convinced I understood what you're trying to achieve, but I believe you just want to merge/join number of errors for a given error. If so, pandas.join() and pandas.merge() are to help. Check the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will avoid loops with Pandas